# Java Quarkus remove methods from Swagger

Tags: class, methods, swagger, quarkus

I am using an Swagger interface for a REST API app in Quarkus and seems that all my methods/Classes are show on Swagger, so i want to removed some of them, to not be visible anymore into Swagger.
I have try with @Hidden, @Ignore, @Operation(hidden = true), and so one but those Classes are still visible there. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried @Schema(hidden=true) Pojo classes that are used as input or output typically ends up in the schema model. For methods that represents an operation, @Operation(hidden=true) should work

Comment: Yes i have try both and that method is still visible into Swagger :(

Comment: Then I would suggest to log a issue, with a small reproducer so that I can look at it as it might be a bug

Comment: Sure, where i need to report this ? I also can give you my example, i did it on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/22429 but if should be on somewhere else please let me know.

Comment: That is perfect thank you. I asked some more details on the issue

Answer (score 1):

Adding @Operation(hidden=true) to a method works for me.
Adding @Schema(hidden=true) to class not working for me.